# Multiple JOIN with TYPEORM

Tags: javascript, sql, typeorm

I'm new on `typeorm`, maybe someone can resolve my problem.
I have some query like :

```
SELECT t1.id,t2.id_2,t3.event,t3.column1,t4.column1 FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.event = t3.event
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.id = t2.id_2 WHERE t3.event = 2019
```

How to convert this query to `typeorm`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Let's break them one by one, shall we?
Assuming you know how then it would be simple:

```
await getManager()
        .createQueryBuilder(table1, 't1')
        .select('t1.id', 't1_id')
        .addSelect('t2.id_2', 't2_id_2')
        .addSelect('t3.event', 't3_event')
        .addSelect('t4.column1', 't4_column1') // up to this point: SELECT t1.id,t2.id_2,t3.event,t3.column1,t4.column1 FROM table1 t1
        .innerJoin(table2, 't2', 't1.id = t2.id') //INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
        .innerJoin(table3, 't3', 't2.event = t3.event') // INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.event = t3.event
        .innerJoin(table4, 't4', 't4.id = t2.id_2') // INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.id = t2.id_2 
        .where('t3.event = 2019') // WHERE t3.event = 2019
        .getRawMany() // depend on what you need really
```

You can refer to this to check what output would you like: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#getting-values-using-querybuilder

Whether you want the data as entities (`getOne` and `getMany`) or what it is(`getRawOne` and `getRawMany`)

Comment: If the sentence starts with ``.addSelect``, you may experience aggregate problem. First .addSelect should be ``.select``

Comment: True, I usually start with `.select` for the first one. thanks @umutyerebakmaz for noticing that.

Comment: If I use an injected repository to create a Query Builder, the `getMany` method returns an empty array while the `getRawMany()` method returns the expected result. Is this expected behavior of NestJS TypeORM 7.1.5?